# Unable to read plist from a bundle outside my own app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

What am I doing wrong? Trying to read Info.plist of Calendar.app into an array but I get nil array. Here is my code:

```
NSBundle* xyzbundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents"];
    // Path to the plist
    NSString *path = [xyzbundle pathForResource:
                      @"Info" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Build the array from the plist
    NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // Show the string values
    for (NSString *str in array2)
        NSLog(@"--%@", str);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your app lives in a sandbox different from Calendar's and hence the call probably fails for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do it. iOS kernel creates a sandbox environment for each of the application. Any application can not read/write data of other application. There are some possible exceptions but in general you cant do it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But just as a matter of interest, what are  the exceptions?

Comment: When your application creates a reader application (which reads .doc, .pptx etc file) using documentInteractionController, and some other application wants to open the same file, your application will be listed which can open these docs. If user selects your app to read that file then that file will be injected into your application to read it.